# Issues with TensorFlow-GPU on Nvidia K2200 (Manjaro/Arch-Linux)

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

I set up my other computer to run TensorFlow (Manjaro-Linux) so I am not using my main system for long computations, I have installed everything through the repository with

`sudo pacman -S cuda cudnn python-tensorflow-opt-cuda`

which is precisely what I did with my other system running a GTX 1060, I updated all my header-files and linux-kernel but I am receiving an error from tensorflow when trying to run my code such that:

```
2021-06-24 12:17:16.984616: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.compat.v2.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
WARNING:root:Limited tf.summary API due to missing TensorBoard installation.
2021-06-24 12:17:25.310893: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2021-06-24 12:17:25.530511: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-06-24 12:17:25.531007: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1733] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: NVIDIA Quadro K2200 computeCapability: 5.0
coreClock: 1.124GHz coreCount: 5 deviceMemorySize: 3.94GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 74.65GiB/s
2021-06-24 12:17:25.541584: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
2021-06-24 12:17:25.662406: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.11
2021-06-24 12:17:25.662508: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublasLt.so.11
2021-06-24 12:17:25.712766: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10
2021-06-24 12:17:25.744087: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10
2021-06-24 12:17:25.783408: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.11
2021-06-24 12:17:25.829728: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.11
2021-06-24 12:17:25.847623: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.8
2021-06-24 12:17:25.847767: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-06-24 12:17:25.848155: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-06-24 12:17:25.848463: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1871] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
Found 20580 images belonging to 120 classes.
2021-06-24 12:17:26.485288: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-06-24 12:17:26.515400: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-06-24 12:17:26.516586: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1733] Found device 0 with properties: 
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: NVIDIA Quadro K2200 computeCapability: 5.0
coreClock: 1.124GHz coreCount: 5 deviceMemorySize: 3.94GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 74.65GiB/s
2021-06-24 12:17:26.516645: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-06-24 12:17:26.517055: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-06-24 12:17:26.517521: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1871] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2021-06-24 12:17:26.536155: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
2021-06-24 12:17:31.411471: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1258] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-06-24 12:17:31.411503: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1264]      0 
2021-06-24 12:17:31.411509: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1277] 0:   N 
2021-06-24 12:17:31.411682: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-06-24 12:17:31.412043: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-06-24 12:17:31.412421: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:937] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2021-06-24 12:17:31.412844: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1418] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 3398 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: NVIDIA Quadro K2200, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 5.0)
2021-06-24 12:17:31.430573: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/process_util.cc:146] Creating new thread pool with default inter op setting: 2. Tune using inter_op_parallelism_threads for best performance.
2021-06-24 12:17:31.556036: F ./tensorflow/core/kernels/random_op_gpu.h:244] Non-OK-status: GpuLaunchKernel(FillPhiloxRandomKernelLaunch<Distribution>, num_blocks, block_size, 0, d.stream(), key, counter, gen, data, size, dist) status: Internal: no kernel image is available for execution on the device
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Can anyone help me resolve this?

**EDIT**
Here is the `nvidia-smi` and `nvcc --version` these were downloaded with pacman
[image]

Comment: Your quadro K2200 is a compute capability 5.0 device.  Your build of TF supports 1060 (CC 6.1) devices but does not support CC 5.0 devices.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thats exactly what I was looking for thank you, I was searching for what versions of tensorflow support CC 5.0 but I couldn't find anything specific. Thank you very much, so going from this what would you recommend I install? How do I find what TF builds support what CC